# Rotate only 4 bits in a byte in Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a problem with 8086 assembly. I have to rotate only 4 bits with the operation `rol` or `ror`. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to rotate 4 bits of a value on themselves ? Do you need to preserve the rest of the value ?

Comment: Is this what you want to do? Left rotation: `value = ((value<<1)&0x0f) | (value >> 3)` Right rotation: `value = (value>>1) | ((value<<3) & 0x0f)`. Or do you need to preserve higher bits (here I assume they are always `0`)?

Comment: Which 4 bits? Do you want the `C` flag to contain the last bit shifted out?

Answer (score 1):

On a "pure" 8086/8088 you have to initialize `CL`:

```
mov cl, 4
rol ax, cl
```

Since 80286 you can use an immediate value:

```
rol ax, 4
```